# Document click not working with some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    alert();
});
```

The problem that when I click on some elements like the `bootstrap dropdown menu` or `chosen.js` or `bootstrap_sellect.js` the alert doesn't display.

As I understand these scripts prevent this but how can pass this and getting an alert when I click on anything on my page?

Comment: You can use the capturing phase of the event.

Comment: @RolandStarke can you give me an example?

Comment: I would recommend googling it.

Comment: @John see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/965834. Basically you need to use the vanilla DOM implementation and make use the third argument of `addEventListener`. But you should read the whole post.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually unbind all bootstrap events from dropdown menus, with [namespaced events in jquery](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/):

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    alert();
});
$('.dropdown-toggle').off('.bs');
```